# Raspberry Pi 3 wlan0 not working after upgrade

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I am trying to get working my raspberry pi. I did `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and now the wifi stopped working.
I also plugged in the camera if that's not a problem.

`dmesg` doesn't show anything about wlan0.

if I do `sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup wlan0` I get this:

```
ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to bring up wlan0.
```

I didn't touch the /etc/network/interfaces file so it's as default like this:

```
interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Any ideas what should be wrong?

**EDIT**
Also if I do ifconfig, `wlan0` is not there

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, here is a working configuration which allows pi3 to use wireless connection automatically if a wired one is not available:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
  wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

#this line must always be here
iface default inet dhcp
```

Comment: Thank You very much, I'll try that tomorrow. now it's too late to try that stuff, but thank You.

Comment: I had the same problem but this did not help :(